# Spring boot filter is ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, filter

I m trying to create a filter, but it is ignored

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class CarsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        httpServletResponse.addHeader("X", "XX");
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Did I forget to do smth?

Comment: Dumb question: How are you checking that the Filter is ignored?

There is one more method `httpServletResponse.setHeader("X", "XX");` try that too.

Comment: Is the component picked up by component scan?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti I'm checking it with test and I tried to do some System.out.println() in the filter - both showed nothing. setHeader didn t help:(

Comment: @mvmn how can I check it?

Comment: You can create a constructor without parameters and add System.out there or place a breakpoint if you debug in IDE.

Comment: @mvmn nope, constructor is not called

Comment: There's your answer - the component is never created. Thus the filter doesn't get registered and applied. You need to check your component scan. Do you have a @ComponentScan annotation in your code? Does it define any packages explicitly?

Comment: @mvmn ups, sorry, my mistake, the component is created, it is in ComponentScan and the constructor is called.. But not doFilterInternal method

Comment: if you are writing an integration test using webAppContextSetup you need to call addFilter() method.

This is not needed if you are actually starting up the server

Comment: @Todoy sorry, I m noob, where should I call this method?

Comment: as a reminder this is how you would do it in a integration test
When setting up the test context.

    \@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    \@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).addFilter(...).build();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the absent of pom dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Instead the Filter was loaded from some java library and therefor compilation was successful (can be removed in module settings)